# gomobile: command not found

Tags: go, ubuntu, github-actions, gomobile

I have some codes written in **golang** which is compiled to **aar** and used as library in android app via **gomobile**. On my windows machine everything works well as I have everything configured correctly. Now I am trying to automate the build process using GitHub action and having trouble setting it up using ubuntu. The problems I am having I believe they are associated with setting PATH which on ubuntu.

Here is my workflow for building my project

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - actions

name: "Build & Release"
jobs:
  generate:
    name: Generate codes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v3
        with:
          go-version: '1.18'

      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Installing go server dependencies
        working-directory: server
        run: |
          go install

      - name: setup-android-tools
        uses: maxim-lobanov/setup-android-tools@v1
        with:
          packages: ndk;19.2.5345600

      - name: Build aar
        working-directory: server
        run: |
          go get -d golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
          gomobile init
          gomobile bind -v -o ../client/app/libs/server.aar -target=android ./lib

      - name: Push aar to release
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "${{ matrix.dir }}/client/app/libs/*aar"
          tag: v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The following is Go ENV as printed by setup-go

```
  GO111MODULE=""
  GOARCH="amd64"
  GOBIN=""
  GOCACHE="/home/runner/.cache/go-build"
  GOENV="/home/runner/.config/go/env"
  GOEXE=""
  GOEXPERIMENT=""
  GOFLAGS=""
  GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
  GOHOSTOS="linux"
  GOINSECURE=""
  GOMODCACHE="/home/runner/go/pkg/mod"
  GONOPROXY=""
  GONOSUMDB=""
  GOOS="linux"
  GOPATH="/home/runner/go"
  GOPRIVATE=""
  GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
  GOROOT="/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.18.2/x64"
  GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
  GOTMPDIR=""
  GOTOOLDIR="/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.18.2/x64/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
  GOVCS=""
  GOVERSION="go1.18.2"
  GCCGO="gccgo"
  GOAMD64="v1"
  AR="ar"
  CC="gcc"
  CXX="g++"
  CGO_ENABLED="1"
  GOMOD="/dev/null"
  GOWORK=""
  CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
  CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
  CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
  CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
  CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
  PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
  GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1913149098=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

And the following is the actual error I get when executing gomobile

> go: downloading golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20220518205345-8578da9835fd
> go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.4.2 go: downloading
> golang.org/x/tools v0.1.8-0.20211022200916-316ba0b74098 go:
> downloading golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1
> go: upgraded golang.org/x/mobile v0.0.0-20220504144722-50dca8fc073d =>
> v0.0.0-20220518205345-8578da9835fd
> /home/runner/work/_temp/8ee34a1b-b28d-4781-9668-9aa41d593cce.sh: line
> 2: gomobile: command not found

How can I successifully build `aar` using github action. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kateile/android-app-with-golang) for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using this step to configure `gomobile` once you setup Go on your runner:

```yaml
- name: Install Gomobile
  run: |
      go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile@latest
      go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind@latest
      go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gobind
      go get golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile
      gomobile init
   env:
      GOPROXY: https://proxy.golang.org,direct
      GO111MODULE: "on"
```

If it doesn't work out, I would be happy to look into this further and raise a fix on your GitHub repository itself :)

Comment: Thanks for response. But all golang configurations are  handled by this action I believe `uses: actions/setup-go@v3` Or do I miss something?

Comment: Can you please try adding this? I am sure it should work :)

Comment: I didn't try it at first. But I really works. Sorry for doubting this answer.

Answer (score -1):

download & install `go` from here ( https://go.dev/dl/ )
open cmd type `go install golang.org/x/mobile/cmd/gomobile@latest`
after download `gomobile init` work.